# Cannot read property "sratsWith" of null. npm

Tags: npm

Всем привет. Когда выполняю команду npm install -g expo-cli. Вылезает вот такое чудо: Cannot read property "sratsWith" of null. А если задать прокси 127.0.0.1:3000
, то будет другая ошибка. Но прокси я не использую, и они равны null. Извините за, возможно, нубский вопрос, но не могу найти решение. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решено:
Заменить http://registry.npmjs.org на  https://registry.npmjs.org

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org
```